# System not shutting down properly

Tags: hardware, archlinux, image, power-management

I'm running Arch, and when I shut down with the `poweroff` command (or with `shutdown -h now`) the 3 LEDs mentioned stay on.  In addition, if I've plugged it into a screen, it displays

```
> POWER OFF
System halted
```

but doesn't actually power off - this text, along with the normal shutdown text, remains on the screen, and text I type on the keyboard still appears.

I assume that this means it isn't shutting down correctly, so what should I do to fix it?  I've tried `dd`-ing over again, and the problem has persisted.

If it makes a difference, the last message printed before it claims to power off is `Remounting Root Filesystem Read-only`.  I'm not sure if this is what it's supposed to do or not.

This is happening on a card where I've just `dd`'ed the `.img` I downloaded from the [Raspberry Pi website](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads), and it has persisted after copying the image again.  It works fine in every other way that I've tried, and it boots up fine!

Sorry for only adding 1 tag - I couldn't find anything else appropriate!

EDIT:
It seems to shutdown properly under the Debian image, so is this an arch problem rather than a raspberry problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## It's fine

It's shutting down just fine. If you check the schematic, you'll see there is no power management. From USB in to the SoC is just copper (and a fuse), so the chip stays powered up even when it's shut down.

### What do I do once I have run `shutdown -h now`?

Just remove the USB from the socket.

Comment: My problem is that the chip seems to still be able to do things - it's shut down the ssh daemon, but it still passes what I type through to the screen.  This doesn't happen with the wheezy image.  Is that just what Arch systems do?

Comment: That doesn't really matter. As long as the file systems are not writeable, you can yank the power cord. Your Raspberry Pi has already told you that (`Remounting Root Filesystem Read-only`), so your data's safe.